# Is this sequence of functions uniformly convergent?

Tags: analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0<a<b$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n(x):=\left(1+\frac{\ln x}{n}\right)^n$.

Then it is easy to see that $\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ pointwise, where $f(x)=x$.

Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: For a>1, you can use Dini's theorem.

Comment: @G.F: If $a<1$, then it seems possible to handle the intervals $[a,1]$ and $[1,b]$ separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$f_n(x)\le f(x)$$ therefore we need to show that there exists $N$ such that for $0<a\le x\le b$ and $n>N$ $$0\le f(x)-f_n(x)<\epsilon$$we need to show that $$\max_{a\le x\le b} f(x)-f_n(x)$$can be bounded arbitrarily small for $N$ being sufficiently large. Now note that$$\max_{a\le x\le b} f(x)-f_n(x)=\max_{x_0\text{ is a critical point in }[a,b]}\Big\{a-f_n(a),b-f_n(b),x_0-f_n(x_0)\Big\}$$where $x_0$ is a critical point of $x-f_n(x)$ since $x-f_n(x)$ is differentiable over $[a,b]$ i.e. for $x_0$:$$1=f'_n(x_0)\to \left(1+{\ln x\over n}\right)^{n-1}=x_0$$by substituting we obtain $$x_0-f_n(x_0)=-{x_0\ln x_0\over n}$$therefore$$\max_{a\le x\le b} f(x)-f_n(x)=\max_{x_0\text{ is a critical point in }[a,b]}\Big\{a-f_n(a),b-f_n(b),x_0-f_n(x_0)\Big\}\\=\max_{x_0\text{ is a critical point in }[a,b]}\Big\{a-f_n(a),b-f_n(b),{-x_0\ln x_0\over n}\Big\}$$but both $a-f_n(a)$ and $b-f_n(b)$ tend to $0$ and ${-x_0\ln x_0\over n}$ is bounded whenever $a\le x_0\le b$. Therefore the proof is complete.